# Vue - reload module on router push

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I everyone. I am quite new to Vue.js.
So i have this api module

```
axios.create({
  baseURL: URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}'
  }
})
```

When i am in the login page and no token is set (localStorage.getItem('token') returns null) the module is already loaded since it is used for login request. When login is successful, i perform `localStorage.setItem('token', token)` but unfortunately the api module does not update its token until i manually refresh the page from the browser (i guess it doesn't refresh on its own since it is a single page application) ending up in my api requests to have null token until i refresh.

How would you solve this issue?

At first i thought "it's a login, it's ok if i make the page reload" so i switched from `this.$router.push('/')` to `this.$router.go('/')` but the navigation to the index gets broken.

Any solution of any kind will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check the [global default](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) options, you can set global headers along with adding to localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend wrapping your API service in a [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) and using that to manage your axios instance. An implementation could look like this.

You want to [set the token explicitly](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults) in your axios instance whenever you set it.

> ApiService.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');

// Function to create an axios instance.
const axiosFactory = (options) => axios.create({
    ...options,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    }
});

// To set the token in axios and save it in localStorage
const setTokenFactory = (axios) => (token) => {
    localStorage.item('token', token);
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
}

// Vue plugin to set $api to axios and expose a setToken function in Vue.
const install = (Vue, axios) => {
    Vue.mixin({
        setToken: (token) => {
            setTokenFactory(Vue.protoype.$api)(token);
        }
    });
    Vue.prototype.$api = axios;
}

// Create an axios instance
const api = axiosFactory({
    baseURL: /* URL */
});
const setToken = setTokenFactory(api);
module.exports = {
    api,
    setToken,
    plugin: {
        install
    }
};
```

> In your `main.js`

```js
const ApiService = require('./ApiService');
Vue.use(ApiService.plugin, ApiService.api);
```

To use the api outside of Vue you can use it like:

```
const { api, setToken } = require('./ApiService');

api.get();
setToken(token);
```

And in Vue, you can use axios using `this.$api`.
To set the token when user logs in, use the `setToken` function using `this.setToken(token)`

Comment: Seems nice, i will try but i would also need to call that $api in other modules (outside of components). The reason is i use that config you gave me as a default, then i redefine a new module for every endpoint i need to call. At that point i import my endpoint request module inside the component from which i need to call the imported endpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately $api does not seem to be available in those modules. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, this will only work if you want to use axios just with vue. For outside of that, I'd say wrap axios in a different function. I'll edit the answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

After login you can also set the token by yourself,
Either after login get the token as response and set it, or ask the token from some other request.

Comment: That's what i already do but the problem is that the value of the token inside the api module is not updated.

Comment: Have you tried through developer console, try set and get the value and see what happens.

Comment: I added a console log above the axios.create with `localStorage.getItem('token')` and it logs only once when the page is first loaded (landing on the login page). Since it is a single page application, the module stays the same and never outputs any log again until i refresh the page.

Comment: Also in the network tab i can see my api requests being made with `Authorization: Bearer null` which confirms this fact.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code where you set the token.